# i want find loudspeaker state of android phone during telephone call conversation

Tags: android, speakerphone

I want to find loudspeaker state during call conversation. like speaker state true/ false.
my code in call receiver

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
Log.v("Loud_Speaker_state", "" + audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn());
```

Comment: What is the error ? Can you add error log if any ?

Comment: Hi Nakul, Actually the thing is i need the status of the speaker whether it is in on or Off during the Phone call.  my log                                             V/Loud_Speaker_state: false

Comment: isSpeakerphoneOn() returning correct status. you haven't set it ON. Use this to set it ON audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

Also add permissions 
RECORD_AUDIO and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS